# Implement a method in Javascript that calculates the level of a tree node

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-search-tree

Given a tree such as the following - please note this is NOT a binary tree:

```
                           root
                         /      \
                        A        B
                       / \      / \
                      C   D    E   F
                    / \ \
                   G  H  I
```

I would like to write a method, which returns the level of the node I call the method on. For example, when calling `C.getLevel()` I am expecting the return value 2, assuming the level of the root node is 0.

Each node has but two properties: a name and an array of its direct children.

Since I am working with a tree here, I have a feeling I need to solve this issue recursively. So, in a first step, I have to figure out an exit condition - when is my method going to return? Most likely when there are no children.

I don't really have a good approach for this issue, but just to give us something to work with, I'll post a start method:

```
getLevel(level = 0) {
    if (this.children.length === 0) {
        return level;
    }

    for (let child of this.children) {
        level = child.getLevel(level + 1);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Which are the classes you have defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the search from the root and then look to find the node. This could either be based on a node instance that is given as argument, or on a name that the target node has ("C" in the example).

Note that I prefer to call this aspect *depth* instead of *level* -- but it's [the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology).

Here is an implementation that searches for the node by name, starting at the root (I named the method `getDepth`):

```js
class Node {
    constructor(name, ...children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }
    getDepth(name) {
        if (this.name == name) return 0;
        for (const child of this.children) {
            const level = child.getDepth(name);
            if (level >= 0) return level + 1;
        }
        return -1; // Not found here
    }
}

// Build the example tree
const root = new Node("root",
    new Node("A",
        new Node("C",
            new Node("G"),
            new Node("H"),
            new Node("I")
        ),
        new Node("D")
    ),
    new Node("B",
        new Node("E"),
        new Node("F")
    )
);

const level = root.getDepth("C");
console.log(level); // 2
```

You mentioned an opposite method signature in comments, which is also a possibility. Like this:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(name, ...children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }
    getDepthWithRespectTo(root) {
        if (this === root) return 0;
        for (const parent of root.children) {
            const level = this.getDepthWithRespectTo(parent);
            if (level >= 0) return level + 1;
        }
        return -1; // Not found here
    }
}

// Build the example tree, and keep a reference to node "C"
let node;
const root = new Node("root",
    new Node("A",
        node = new Node("C",
            new Node("G"),
            new Node("H"),
            new Node("I")
        ),
        new Node("D")
    ),
    new Node("B",
        new Node("E"),
        new Node("F")
    )
);

const level = node.getDepthWithRespectTo(root);
console.log(level); // 2
```

Comment: the author want's having `Node::getLevel()`...

Comment: Yes,  @silentmantra, I renamed it to use more common tree language: depth.

Comment: Anyway that's another use case unfortunately...

Comment: What do you mean? It's the path's distance from the root to the target node. See [terminology section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) on the Wikipedia article, @silentmantra.

Comment: The author wants `Node::getLevel()` not some other design.

Comment: Other design? This is just a name of a method; if they want a different name, no problem, but that is not the essence of the question, is it? Anyway I added to my answer a note as to why I propose a different name, so there cannot be any confusion.

Comment: @trincot thx so much, this is a great answer! You are calculating the distance between the node that the method is called on and the node that is passed into the method as parameter. So in order to get the level of an arbitrary node, I will have to call `root.getDepth(node)`. I think it would be a bit more intuitive, if I was calling the method like `node.getDepthWithRespectTo(root)`. It's probably not possible to pass in the root node as a parameter to the function, is it? I don't see how we could find the name of the node we're looking for this way, but maybe I am, again, too blind to see.

Comment: Sure, that method is also a possibility. I added it to my answer.

Comment: thanks so much @trincot, you are a real life savior!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to iterate the whole tree anyway, it might be easier to precompute depths for all nodes at once:

```
function setDepth(node, depth) {
    node.depth = depth
    for (let c of node.children)
        setDepth(c, depth + 1)
}

setDepth(root, 0)
```

and then just pick `someNode.depth`

Comment: I'm worried after that the tree becames static and you cannot move nodes without recalculating depths of all nodes over and over. Also the author implies you cannot add extra properties. IF we add a property it's better to be `parent` like a normal tree has

Comment: @silentmantra: so what? it will be a fraction of second even for millions of nodes.

Comment: @god the design isnt reactive and error-prone. Manually re-calculating the tree means somewhere you'll forget to do this. And that's also against the author design to have only `name` and `children` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class TreeNode {
      constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
      }
    
      addChild(child) {
        this.children.push(child);
      }
    }
    
    function calculateNodeLevel(root, targetValue) {
      if (root.value === targetValue) {
        return 0; // Found the target node at the root level
      }
    
      for (let child of root.children) {
        const level = calculateNodeLevel(child, targetValue);
        if (level !== -1) {
          return level + 1; // Found the target node in a child subtree
        }
      }
    
      return -1; // Target node not found in the tree
    }
    
    // Example usage:
    const tree = new TreeNode(1);
    const child1 = new TreeNode(2);
    const child2 = new TreeNode(3);
    const grandchild = new TreeNode(4);
    child2.addChild(grandchild);
    tree.addChild(child1);
    tree.addChild(child2);
    
    console.log(calculateNodeLevel(tree, 1)); // Output: 0
    console.log(calculateNodeLevel(tree, 2)); // Output: 1
    console.log(calculateNodeLevel(tree, 3)); // Output: 1
    console.log(calculateNodeLevel(tree, 4)); // Output: 2
    console.log(calculateNodeLevel(tree, 5)); // Output: -1 (Node not found)

In this example, the TreeNode class represents a node in the tree, and it has a value property to store the value of the node and a children array to store its child nodes.

The calculateNodeLevel function takes a root node and a targetValue as input. It recursively traverses the tree starting from the root and checks if the value of each node matches the targetValue. If a match is found, it returns the level of that node (0 for the root level, 1 for its children, and so on). If the targetValue is not found in the tree, it returns -1.

In the example usage section, a simple tree is created, and the calculateNodeLevel function is called with different target values to demonstrate its usage and output.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).